# connect to drive through ssh hops

Tags: tunnel, sshfs

I am trying to connect my hdd that is installed on my raspberry pi over the internet. I have a server somewhere that is accessible through ssh that I can use as a hub.

> A (home) <----> B (server) <----> C (pi)

I can create a tunnel from the server B to the pi through a reverse tunnel like this:

> ssh -f -N -R 10000:localhost:22 user@remoteserver

So now I can connect from home to server B, and then to the pi. But I want this in one step, and with sshfs. So How can I use sshfs such that it uses this tunnel and connects home to the pi?

edit: 
I can probably mount the pi drive on system B, and then mount this again on system A, but would this be significantly slower, or bad for some other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh user@remoteserver nc %h %p' user@yourpi` to get SSH access through your server.

I'm not sure if sshfs recognize the `-o ProxyCommand` option from the cli (and can't test it right now), but you can try.

The other way is to edit your .ssh/config file and add:

```
Host pi
   ProxyCommand ssh user@remoteserver nc -q0 %h %p
```

And then to simply use `sshfs user@pi[:directory] mountpoint`

All this is assuming you have netcat (nc) installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Though the pi itself is not accessible through the internet (that's why I had create a reverse tunnel from the pi to remoteserver). So what should user@yourpi be?

Comment: Well, the `yourpi` part is just the address you use from your server ;)

Comment: ah perfect, thanks! in my case its localhost then, and I have to specify the port. So this works for me:
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh user@remoteserver nc %h %p' user@localhost -p 10000